# Python comparing two strings

Tags: python

Is there a function to compare how many characters two strings (of the same length) differ by? I mean only substitutions. For example, AAA would differ from AAT by 1 character.

Comment: [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice use case for the zip function!

```
def count_substitutions(s1, s2):
    return sum(x != y for (x, y) in zip(s1, s2))
```

Usage:

```
>>> count_substitutions('AAA', 'AAT')
1
```

From the docs:

```
zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Comment: Might I suggest avoiding variable names starting with lowercase L? I thought you were comparing 11 to
 1

Comment: @mhlester: You have a point there. But what are good abbreviations for several letters in a string?

Comment: If it's only used in a comprehension, it doesn't much matter. I fully support your x/y :)

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
>>> str1 = "AAA"
>>> str2 = "AAT"
>>> sum(1 for x,y in enumerate(str1) if str2[x] != y)
1
>>> str1 = "AAABBBCCC"
>>> str2 = "ABCABCABC"
>>> sum(1 for x,y in enumerate(str1) if str2[x] != y)
6
>>>
```

The above solution uses [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

---

Because `True` can evaluate to `1`, you could even do:

```
>>> str1 = "AAA"
>>> str2 = "AAT"
>>> sum(str2[x] != y for x,y in enumerate(str1))
1
>>>
```

But I personally prefer the first solution because it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what poke said I would suggest the [jellyfish](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jellyfish/0.1.2) package. It has several distance measures like what you are asking for. Example from the documentation:

```
IN [1]: jellyfish.damerau_levenshtein_distance('jellyfish', 'jellyfihs')
OUT[1]: 1
```

or using your example:

```
IN [2]: jellyfish.damerau_levenshtein_distance('AAA','AAT')
OUT[2]: 1
```

This will work for many different string lengths and should be able to handle most of what you throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to simon's answer, but you don't have to zip things in order to just call a function on the resulting tuples because that's what `map` does anyway (and `itertools.imap` in Python 2). And there's a handy function for `!=` in `operator`. Hence:

```
sum(map(operator.ne, s1, s2))
```

Comment: Could the operator.ne be replaced with a lambda function?

Comment: @goodcow: sure, but I don't think it would improve things in any way other than reducing the number of `import` lines at the top of your file :-)

Comment: Nice! This version is quite a bit faster than my version on Python 3.3!